# Integral inequality $e^{\int _0^1f\left(x\right)dx-1\:}\le \frac{1}{4}\int _0^1\left(x+1\right)e^{f\left(x\right)}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, integral-inequality

Let $f:\left[0,1\right]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Show that:
$$e^{\int _0^1f\left(x\right)dx-1\:}\le \frac{1}{4}\int _0^1\left(x+1\right)e^{f\left(x\right)}dx$$
How should this inequality be approached? It probably has a straightforward solution but I could use a hint.

Comment: $e^{\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx}\leq \int_{0}^{1}e^{f(x)}\,dx$ by Jensen's inequality seems like a good starting point.

Comment: is the $-1$ located outside of the integral?

Comment: Yes, that's why it's after the dx.

Comment: i think $\int_0^1\log(x+1)dx=\log(4)-1$ together with Jack's hint will be enough to answer this question

Comment: How does $\int_0^1ln\left(x+1\right)dx$ lead to a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In explicit terms: Jensen's inequality gives $$ e^{\int_{0}^{1}g(x)\,dx}\leq \int_{0}^{1}e^{g(x)}\,dx $$
and if we pick $g(x)=\log(x+1)+f(x)$ this gives
$$ e^{\log\frac{4}{e}+\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx} \leq \int_{0}^{1}(x+1) e^{f(x)}\,dx $$
or
$$ \frac{4}{e}\cdot e^{\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx} \leq \int_{0}^{1}(x+1) e^{f(x)}\,dx $$
or
$$ e^{\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx-1} \leq \frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{1}(x+1) e^{f(x)}\,dx $$
as wanted.